Consequences of not closing an aiohttp session
I wrote two classes intended for a library that wrap REST api calls in a convenient way for the user. The library is intended for use in a FastApi application and also in research projects. I read that it is good practice to reuse the session object in order to reuse the connections so I create a session once for each instance like so:
class ApiWrapper:
  def __init__(self, ...):
    self.session = None
    ...

  async def call_api(self, ...):
    if self.session is None:
      self.session = await aiohttp.ClientSession().__aenter__()
    ...
    async with self.session.post(...)...
    ...

My goal in implementing the classes like this is to abstract away the existence of the session from the user but at the same time get the performance benefits of reusing it between requests.
With this current implementation, there is no code that closes the session, and I would like to know what issues this might cause for the applications that use these classes and the remote services that they wrap.
Concerning resource leakage - both in the case of the FastAPI service and the research projects, there will be probably be only one or a few instances of each class. I'm not sure if this is a thing to worry about as these resources will be used for the duration of these programs anyway.
The other thing I am worried about is if leaving open connections to the remote REST service will somehow harm it.
I would like to know

If I should worry about resource leakage in the case of a small amount of instances.
If leaving the sessions open will somehow harm the remote services they wrap.
About other potential problems that not closing the session explicitly might cause
If there is a way to close session in a way that is convenient to the user.
What negative behavior might happen if my assumptions were incorrect and a user creates a large number of instances without closing the contained session.

Edit: The emphasis is that I want these classes to be able to be used not only in the fastapi app but also in small research projects. I don't want the user of these classes to know how to work with the session, therefore the linked answer is irrelevant to this question as it requires to maintain a global state in the project and depend on FastAPI functionalities
thanks

Most servers will close idle connections after a timeout. So you're not harming the remote service.
